# How to work with iframe which is part of a webpage but not getting identified through webdriver?

Tags: selenium

I am trying to automate a webpage using webdriver,here  i am struck with a iframe,which i dont know how to handle.

While i choose css for the iframe by selecting with ,it gives me #xEditingArea

again if I search the same iframe using the css or id,it is not identifying anything.
I tried everything
I want to write some message with the message body which is iframe.

Can anyone guide me how to handle this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If it is only one iFrame on your website you could try to access it with XPath and the tagname.

Answer (score 0):

Directly accessing iframes is not possible, it has its own DOM elements and we have to switch to that particular frame and then perform the actions you want.

To select the iframe you want to work with, do:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("frame1");
```

Now, your driver set to work with the DOM the iframe one.

It's important to remember that maybe switching "back" will be needed. It's done like this:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Python Selenium WebDriver, you can access a frame using:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.switch_to_frame("fame_name_or_id")
```

If you want to confirm that the frame was access correctly, just print out the page contents using:

```
print browser.page_source
```